# How to detect if Rails / Devise current_user is a guest user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've got a Rails app running with "real" users and "guest" users via devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user).

Most of the time they can be used indistinguishably, but occasionally I want to be able to tell a "real" logged in user from a "guest" user who didn't log in or create an account yet.

Is there a standard way to do this? (There must be, right?)

Here's a sample of what I'm seeing in `current_user`:

```
=> #<User:0x007fb011620c78
 id: 30,
 email: "guest_143829190430@example.com",
 encrypted_password:
  "$2a$10$MJr8M3JA6/wYCoOz0oBTseoA3zVnLUceY7BeJLRnLgeXfKNMW/k/S",
 reset_password_token: nil,
 reset_password_sent_at: nil,
 remember_created_at: nil,
 sign_in_count: 1,
 current_sign_in_at: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 16:31:44 CDT -05:00,
 last_sign_in_at: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 16:31:44 CDT -05:00,
 current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1",
 last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1",
 created_at: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 16:31:44 CDT -05:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 16:31:44 CDT -05:00,
 first_name: "guest",
 last_name: "guest",
```

I could look at `first_name` / `last_name` / `email`, but that feels flimsy, and I could look for `session[:guest_user_id]` in the session, and that seems like perhaps the way to go, but it just feels like there should be a built in `.is_guest?` or something, and I'd rather use that than write my own.

(My Google-ing and exploration of their codebase has not yet turned up anything... Might have more once I can pull their repo and grep...)

Thanks all!

Best I've got so far would be something like:

```
def is_guest?
  current_user.id == session[:guest_user_id] if current_user && session[:guest_user_id]
end
```

Comment: you could at least shorten it a bit  `def is_guest? current_user && session[:guest_user_id] == current_user.id end`

Answer (score 2):

Without delving into all of the available code, I would suggest that the beginnings of the`current_or_guest_user` method describe the checks that are required. I would create a method from these along the lines of:

```
def is_guest_user?
  # Someone is logged in AND (we have a guest id AND that id matches the current user)
  current_user && (session[:guest_user_id] && session[:guest_user_id] == current_user.id)
end
```

I would add this to the `User` model. Based on that `current_or_guest_user` method I don't expect you'll find anything else built in (as surely they would have used it in that method).

Comment: Yeah that's almost exactly the method I'm using, I just thought for sure there was a better way that I was missing. Maybe not.

Comment: I'd also expect a built in method, search the devise source for uses of `guest_user_id` perhaps to find any.

Comment: I don't think this code could be added to a model, as neither the `current_user` nor `session` method is available inside models.